# Undefined returned from json

Tags: javascript, json

I’m trying to fetch some data, specifically the ‘html’ from the [1] array from the json displayed below. However when I console log welcomeTXT after setting the variable to that json selector it says

```
undefined
```

Any idea why the data is returning as undefined?

```
var welcomeTXT; 

    fetch('http://ip.ip.ip.ip:port/ghost/api/v3/content/pages/?key=276f4fc58131dfcf7a268514e5')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
          console.log(data);
          welcomeTXT = ['pages'][0]['title'];
          console.log(welcomeTXT);
      });


JSON

    {
   "pages":[
      {
         "id":"5efb6bbeeab44526aecc0abb",
         "uuid":"38b78123-e5a8-4346-8f6e-6f57a1a284d0",
         "title":"About Section",
         "slug":"about-section",
         "html":"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>",
         "comment_id":"5efb6bbeeab44526aecc0abb",
         "feature_image":null,
         "featured":false,
         "visibility":"public",
         "created_at":"2020-06-30T16:43:42.000+00:00",
         "updated_at":"2020-06-30T16:58:53.000+00:00",
         "published_at":"2020-06-30T16:58:37.000+00:00",
         "custom_excerpt":null,
         "codeinjection_head":null,
         "codeinjection_foot":null,
         "custom_template":null,
         "canonical_url":null,
         "url":"/about-section/",
         "excerpt":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor\nincididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis\nnostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.\nDuis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu\nfugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in\nculpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
         "reading_time":0,
         "page":true,
         "og_image":null,
         "og_title":null,
         "og_description":null,
         "twitter_image":null,
         "twitter_title":null,
         "twitter_description":null,
         "meta_title":null,
         "meta_description":null
      },
      {
         "id":"5efb6f53eab44526aecc0ac4",
         "uuid":"26463d5f-011e-46b3-a1e2-60e213e33f6f",
         "title":"Welcome",
         "slug":"welcome",
         "html":"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>",
         "comment_id":"5efb6f53eab44526aecc0ac4",
         "feature_image":null,
         "featured":false,
         "visibility":"public",
         "created_at":"2020-06-30T16:58:59.000+00:00",
         "updated_at":"2020-06-30T16:59:02.000+00:00",
         "published_at":"2020-06-30T16:59:02.000+00:00",
         "custom_excerpt":null,
         "codeinjection_head":null,
         "codeinjection_foot":null,
         "custom_template":null,
         "canonical_url":null,
         "url":"http:/welcome/",
         "excerpt":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor\nincididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis\nnostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.\nDuis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu\nfugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in\nculpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
         "reading_time":0,
         "page":true,
         "og_image":null,
         "og_title":null,
         "og_description":null,
         "twitter_image":null,
         "twitter_title":null,
         "twitter_description":null,
         "meta_title":null,
         "meta_description":null
      }
   ],
   "meta":{
      "pagination":{
         "page":1,
         "limit":15,
         "pages":1,
         "total":2,
         "next":null,
         "prev":null
      }
   }
}
```

Any help would be wonderful, as I can’t figure out why the JSON isn’t working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot `data` here:

```js
welcomeTXT = data['pages'][0]['title'];
```

Answer (score 1):

In promise then you missed the "data"

> welcomeTXT = ['pages'][0]['title'];

it should be

> welcomeTXT = data['pages'][0]['title'];

```
var welcomeTXT; 
fetch('http://ip.ip.ip.ip4/ghost/api/v3/content/pages/?key=276f4fc58131dfcf7a268514e5')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      welcomeTXT = data['pages'][0]['title'];
      console.log(welcomeTXT);
  });
```